# Vimeo - get all user video ids in array

Tags: php, api, oauth, vimeo

I am new to vimeo API, but I need to connec to an account, then get all ids of uploaded videos and then store them in array. I have some understanding of PHP but frankly all the examples I saw or documentation provided by Vimeo didn' tell me so much, so I am asking if there is somebody who can direct me to some examples how to connnect through oauth and call vimeo methods through my script. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: My issue is simply how to connect to vimeo, how to work with library..can I simply use Index.php code, paste there my keys and then call required methods? I am really stuck..

Answer (score 2):

1.If you need only user videos, you can use curl request to url - http://vimeo.com/api/v2/USERNAME/videos.json where USERNAME is name of vimeo user whose stream you want to get.

example:

```
$curl = curl_init(');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
url_close($curl);
```

2.You can use implementation of Advanced vimeo api for php with OAuth - https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib

Answer (score 1):

Working script with curl

```
<?php 
function curl_download($Url)
   if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
       die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
       }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/tas.htm");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
 return $output;
}


$VimeoVideos = curl_download('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/USER_ID_HERE/videos.json');
 $p = json_decode($VimeoVideos, true);
print_r($p); // result with video ids and other information in array
?>
```

Thanks